# Joomla Community Builder profile template

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla1.7

I have installed community builder on my Joomla installation. I need to understand the Community Builder templating. I cannot understand where templates are and how can I override them. Can I override them by placing files in my site template's html folder, the way Joomla does or else it gets harder to maintain.

Another small problem: I wanna redirect to the profile page after logging in from the CB login page instead of the page that say Hi %username% with a Logout button.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

CB templates are found in the CB plugin manager located through components - CBuilder - Plugin Management, There are a few default templates but most decent ones are commercial, If you happen to find any free ones please let me know.